# How does one show that asymptotically $AdS_3$ spacetimes are locally $AdS_3$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

Time and again I keep reading that any asymptotic $AdS_3$ spacetime is locally isomorphic to $AdS_3$.

I tried to find proof of this by analyzing the Riemann tensor $R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} $ in Ricci decomposition. I found the usual results that the Weyl tensor vanishes in $d=3$. What is left is the trace part ($S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} $) and the semi-tracefree part ($E_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} $) (using wiki conventions [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_decomposition ]) :
$$
R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}  = S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} + E_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu} 
$$
Now by demanding that $T_{\mu\nu}=0$ in the Einstein equations lets the $E_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ part vanish and then I get the well known statement for $AdS_3$ that for appropriate $\Lambda$:
$$
R_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}  = S_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}  = - \frac{1 }{\ell^2} \left(g_{\rho\mu}g_{\mu\sigma} - g_{\rho\nu}g_{\mu\sigma} \right)
$$
Now as I understand it (and please correct me if I'm wrong), stating something is asymptotically $AdS$ is the same as allowing a non-vanishing $E_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$, but  letting it vanish in the appropriate asymptotic limits (??). Now that would mean that the Riemann tensor locally takes on very different forms as above, so I don't get the statement about it locally being $AdS_3$. Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree, I don't know.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where?

Comment: It's in a reader on a password protected page of my uni unfortunately. It introduces Fefferman Graham coordinates and then states that it is always locally ads for d=3. Is this not true? That would explain something...